# Use data outside fetch from API ( React )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I receive an array of objects from the API fetch, but I can't pass it on   `< ResponseTable data={} />` if I pass the car, it works.

```js
import React from 'react'
import ResponseTable from './responsetable'

var car = [{type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"}];

class Table extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  fetchData() {
    return fetch('http://localhost:8000/sprints/23')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.json);
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
      return myJson;
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <ResponseTable data={} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Set the response in state. `car` works because it comes from global scope.

```
class Table extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    }
  }

  fetchData() {
    return fetch('http://localhost:8000/sprints/23')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.json);
    })
    .then((myJson) => {
      this.setState({data: myJson});
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render(){
    return(

      <div>
        <ResponseTable data={this.state.data} />
      </div>

      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you resolve your fetch, you will want to set your state component and then pass that state to your ResponseTable data

```
class Table extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myJson: null // define as null
    }
  }

  fetchData() {
  return fetch('http://localhost:8000/sprints/23')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.json);
  })
  .then((myJson) => {
    this.setState({myJson: myJson})
  });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render(){
    return(

      <div>
        <ResponseTable data={this.state.myJson} />
      </div>

      );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Note we set the `myJson` state as null.

We then fetch the data. I have changed the .then functions to arrow functions so that `this` is scoped to the component.

We then pass `this.state.myJson` as a property to your child component

Answer (score 0):

Why not throw the response into a state object to pass as a prop?

```js
import React from 'react'
import ResponseTable from './responsetable'

var car = [{type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"}];


class Table extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       data: {}
    }
  }

  fetchData() {
  return fetch('http://localhost:8000/sprints/23')
  .then(function(response) {
    this.setState({data: response.json})
    console.log(response.json);
  })
  }

   componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render(){
    return(

      <div>
        <ResponseTable data={this.state.data} />
      </div>

      );
  }
}

export default Table;
```